# Error in Link List, pointer

Tags: c, pointers

what is wrong with this code? This is simply creating a link list and printing it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
    struct node *next;
    int data;
 };

void printLinklist(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void pushData(struct node *head, int val)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    temp->next = head;
    temp->data = val;
    head = temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    pushData(head, 1);
    pushData(head, 2);
    pushData(head, 3);
    pushData(head, 4);
    pushData(head, 5);

    printLinklist(head);
}
```

I know correct way of doing it. For that we will have to pass &head in pushData() function and define argument of this function as double pointer (replace head to *head in pushData() function and passing &head as an argument)

I can't understand the problem in this code.

Comment: what makes the correct way correct? it's interesting you know the "how" but not the "why".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments are always `passed by value`. When calling `pushData()`, the value of `head`, that is the address stored in the pointer variable is copied into the local variable `head` of the function. Changing this won't change the `head` variable in the `main()` function.

If you need that to happen, you have to pass `&head` and then assign value by dereferencing it in the `pushData()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you assign `NULL` to `head` in `main()`, and that never chagnes, it could work like this

```
struct node *pushData(struct node *head, int val)
{
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->data = val;

    return temp;
}
```

and in main

```
int main()
{
    struct node *head;

    head = pushData(head, 1);
    head = pushData(head, 2);
    head = pushData(head, 3);
    head = pushData(head, 4);
    head = pushData(head, 5);

    printLinklist(head);
}
```

passing the pointer only modifies the data the pointer points to, but not the pointer itself.

So in your `pushData()` function, you do this

```
head = temp;
```

which changes the local pointer, and makes it pointer to temp, but once the function returns, the change is lost.

When you pass the address of `head` like `&head`, and then you can alter the pointer because your `head` pointer will be pointing to the pointer itself instead of the data the pointer points to.

Answer (score 0):

The True code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)   
struct node {
    struct node* next;
    int data;
};

void printLinklist(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* temp = head;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* pushData(struct node* head, int val)
{
    struct node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (temp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    temp->next = head;
    temp->data = val;

    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    struct node* head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head = pushData(head, 1);
    head = pushData(head, 2);
    head = pushData(head, 3);
    head = pushData(head, 4);
    head = pushData(head, 5);
    struct node* head2 = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        head2 = head2->next;
    }
    head2->next = NULL;
    printLinklist(head);
}
```